# Syncing in-app purchase between platforms allowed?

Tags: android, ios, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

Is it allowed to keep in sync auto-renewing subscription in Android and iOS via an online account?

That is to say : in Babbel, if I buy an auto-renewing subscription in Android (with the Android system of purchasing), it will be available on my iOS device.
In the same way, if I buy an auto-renewing subscription on iOS (via IAP), the courses will be available on Android too.
Everything is synced into my Babbel account.

Is it allowed (according to Apple guideline about IAP) so that I can reproduce this system in an app of mine? (The content sold being videos)

Thank you very much,

Jery

Comment: A simple solution would be to allow the user to buy some "Gold points" or whatever with the in-App purchase. So when the user switches between his iOS device or his Android one, he just logs to his account and get his points and tools back.

Comment: Hi thank you for your answer. This is indeed a solution I proposed to the client. However, he asked me all the solution possible to keep in sync purchases, and I don't want to tell him that the syncing subscription is allowed if it is not (even if Babbel does it). (When I told about buying Virtual Money, my client feared it would be a little complicated for end users). But Virtual Money is a good idea in my opinion.

Comment: I don't know what Google says about inapp purchase syncing but I'm sure that using Virtual money would be safe for your and your customer.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  Both app stores have provisions to allow for this.  (It's how Kindle, for instance, avoids being kicked out of the App Store even though you purchase content for it from Amazon directly).

There are drop-in libraries like [Frac.as](http://frac.as/) that handle the syncing part for you.